# Is it possible to create a moving geofence?

Tags: geolocation, ads, geofencing, android-geofence, proximity

I want to track how many people are near my moving vehicle, and send them mobile advertisements afterwards. I know geofencing is a great tool to target people in a certain location. I figure the best way to achieve my goal is through a moving geofence that could track how many people came near my vehicle as it drove. However, I am not sure if there is a method to set up a moving geofence. Does anyone have any knowledge on how to do this or what platforms currently offer APIs for this?

I looked into Google's geofencing API and couldn't find anything on moving geofences. I also looked into roam.ai that has a 'moving geofence' API, but it only tracks if multiple users come into contact with each other (not all the people who are in a single geofence).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.